Custom plugin data is not being displayed In Admin Panel
I have created a custom plugin in wordpress, but in Admin Panle data is not being displayed.
My plugin path is E:\xampp\htdocs\wp_project\wp-content\plugins\booked-lbb-properties.php.
Content of booked-lbb-properties.php:
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Booked LB&B Properties
Description: Display booked properties from wp_lbb_bookings table
*/
if (!class_exists('WP_List_Table')) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php';
}


// action function for above hook
function blbb_add_pages() {
    // Add a new submenu under Settings:
    add_menu_page(
        __('Booked LB&B Properties', 'blbb'), 
        __('Booked LB&B Properties', 'blbb'), 
        'manage_options', 
        'blbb-bookings', 
        'blbb_bookings_page',
        46
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'blbb_add_pages');

// blbb_bookings_page() displays the page content for the Booked LB&B Properties submenu
function blbb_bookings_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2><?php _e('Booked LB&B Properties', 'blbb'); ?></h2>
        <?php
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'lbb_bookings';

        // Prepare the list table
        $blbb_list_table = new BLBB_List_Table();
        $blbb_list_table->prepare_items();

        // Display the list table
        ?>
        <form id="blbb-bookings-form">
            <?php
                $blbb_list_table->search_box('Search Properties', 'search_id');
           ?>
            <table>
                <?php $blbb_list_table->display();?>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

// BLBB_List_Table class
class BLBB_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {
    function __construct() {
        global $status, $page;

        // Set parent defaults
        parent::__construct(array(
            'singular' => 'booking',
            'plural'   => 'bookings',
            'ajax'     => false
        ));
    }

    function column_default($item, $column_name) {
        switch ($column_name) {
            case 'booking_id':
            case 'lbb_property_type':
            case 'lbb_property_id':
            case 'user_id':
            case 'guest_name':
            case 'email':
            case 'phone':
            case 'address':
            case 'zip_code':
            case 'city':
            case 'country':
            case 'subscribe':
            case 'check_in_date':
            case 'check_out_date':
            case 'price':
            case 'nights':
            case 'transaction_id':
            case 'payment_intent':
            case 'payment_method':
            case 'payment_status':
            case 'session_id':
            case 'created_at':
                return $item[$column_name];
            default:
                return print_r($item, true); //Show the whole array for troubleshooting purposes
        }
    }

    function get_columns() {
        $columns = array(
            'cb'                => '<input type="checkbox" />',
            'booking_id'        => __('Booking ID', 'blbb'), 
            'lbb_property_type' => __('LB&B Property Type', 'blbb'), 
            'lbb_property_id'   => __('LB&B Property ID', 'blbb'),    
            'user_id'           => __('User ID', 'blbb'),     
            'guest_name'        => __('Guest Name', 'blbb'),
            'email'             => __('Email', 'blbb'),
            'phone'             => __('Phone', 'blbb'),
            'address'           => __('Address', 'blbb'),
            'zip_code'          => __('Zip Code', 'blbb'),
            'city'              => __('City', 'blbb'),
            'country'           => __('Country', 'blbb'),
            'subscribe'         => __('Subscribe', 'blbb'), 
            'check_in_date'     => __('Check In Date', 'blbb'),
            'check_out_date'    => __('Check Out Date', 'blbb'),
            'price'             => __('Price', 'blbb'),
            'nights'            => __('Nights', 'blbb'), 
            'transaction_id'    => __('Transaction ID', 'blbb'), 
            'payment_intent'    => __('Payment Intent', 'blbb'), 
            'payment_method'    => __('Payment Method', 'blbb'), 
            'payment_status'    => __('Payment Status', 'blbb'), 
            'session_id'        => __('Session Id', 'blbb'), 
            'created_at'        => __('Created At', 'blbb'), 
        );
        return $columns;
    }

    function prepare_items() {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'lbb_bookings';

        $query = "SELECT * FROM $table_name";

        $orderby = !empty($_GET["orderby"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["orderby"]) : 'ASC';
        $order = !empty($_GET["order"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["order"]) : '';
        if (!empty($orderby) && !empty($order)) {
            $query .= ' ORDER BY ' . $orderby . ' ' . $order;
        }

        $totalitems = $wpdb->query($query); //return the total number of affected rows
        $perpage = 5;
        $paged = !empty($_GET["paged"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["paged"]) : '';
        if (empty($paged) || !is_numeric($paged) || $paged <= 0) {
            $paged = 1;
        }
        $totalpages = ceil($totalitems / $perpage);

        if (!empty($paged) && !empty($perpage)) {
            $offset = ($paged - 1) * $perpage;
            $query .= ' LIMIT ' . (int) $offset . ',' . (int) $perpage;
        }

        $this->items = $wpdb->get_results($query);

        $this->set_pagination_args(array(
            "total_items" => $totalitems,
            "total_pages" => $totalpages,
            "per_page" => $perpage
        ));
    }
}

I have put the datatype side by from database fields.
'cb'                => '<input type="checkbox" />',
'booking_id'        => __('Booking ID', 'blbb'), bigint(20)   
'lbb_property_type' => __('LB&B Property Type', 'blbb'), varchar(255) 
'lbb_property_id'   => __('LB&B Property ID', 'blbb'), int(255)   
'user_id'           => __('User ID', 'blbb'), int(255)    
'guest_name'        => __('Guest Name', 'blbb'),varchar(255)  
'email'             => __('Email', 'blbb'),varchar(255)   
'phone'             => __('Phone', 'blbb'),varchar(255)   
'address'           => __('Address', 'blbb'),varchar(255) 
'zip_code'          => __('Zip Code', 'blbb'),varchar(255)    
'city'              => __('City', 'blbb'),varchar(255)    
'country'           => __('Country', 'blbb'),varchar(255) 
'subscribe'         => __('Subscribe', 'blbb'),tinyint(1) 
'check_in_date'     => __('Check In Date', 'blbb'),date
'check_out_date'    => __('Check Out Date', 'blbb'),date
'price'             => __('Price', 'blbb'),varchar(255)   
'nights'            => __('Nights', 'blbb'), int(255) 
'transaction_id'    => __('Transaction ID', 'blbb'), varchar(255)
'payment_intent'    => __('Payment Intent', 'blbb'), varchar(255)
'payment_method'    => __('Payment Method', 'blbb'), varchar(255)
'payment_status'    => __('Payment Status', 'blbb'), varchar(50)  
'session_id'        => __('Session Id', 'blbb'), varchar(50)  
'created_at'        => __('Created At', 'blbb'), timestamp

Below is the image that kind of showing in admin panel,

Please help me with this. What did I do wrong here that data is not being displayed in the Table?

$this->items = $wpdb->get_results($query);
when i print this, I get data from database, then why not displaying in the table?

Did you try setting WP_Debug to true?

The get_results method returns Objects by default. But seems you are treating it as an array. Here the reference for get_results: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/

@Klaassiek yes i have setting WP_Debug to true, but there is no any error display regarding this,

And the get_results is set to $output = ARRAY_A?
